# Get a list of all of components of a game object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say, I have a game object in my scene which has 12 components. Some of these components might be of the same type: for example, this game object might have two audio sources. Now, I want to add a C# script to this game object in a way that it collects the name of all of these components (in a list?), and prints them out in the console. How can I do that?

Comment: Check this links I think it can help you

https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-all-components-in-a-gameobject.33575/

https://answers.unity.com/questions/552852/fastest-way-to-get-all-components-on-gameobject.html

Comment: Share your work, ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    Component[] components = GetComponents(typeof(Component));
    for(int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(components[i].name);
    }
```

Comment: @Gordafarid No worries! :)

Comment: This printed out the name of the parent over and over and not the component name

Comment: after five years, i need this ^^ thnx a lot

Answer (score 19):

Use `GetComponents` method to get array of components, as shown below.

```
Component[] components = gameObject.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
foreach(Component component in components) {
    Debug.Log(component.ToString());
}
```

This will also display the duplicate components added to the `GameObject`

Comment: Same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450253/7111561) note that `ToString` returns `name` which is the name of the `GameObject` -> your loop prints always the same name of the gameObject all those components are attached to ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    string text = string.Empty;
    foreach(var component in myGameObject.GetComponents(typeof(Component)))
    {
        text += component.GetType().ToString() + " ";
    }
```

Example output:
"text": "UnityEngine.RectTransform UnityEngine.CanvasRenderer UnityEngine.UI.RawImage UnityEngine.UI.Button DebugLayoverButton UnityEngine.Canvas UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRaycaster UnityEngine.UI.LayoutElement "

Comment: you would be better of using a `StringBuilder` then ;) Or directly go through `string.Join('\n', myGameObject.GetComponents<Component>().Select(c => c.GetType));`